# Animation between Fragment of view pager and another activity

Tags: android, animation

I am working on application in which I am using view pager consists of 3 diff fragments. When I clicked button in fragment I want to show activity. And I want animation in between them. Is it possible? If yes which animation I have to use Transition animation,Layout animation or view animation??

I am new to the animation and didn't know about it. So please give me some good links for that.

Comment: hey I got half of solution of it.. can anyone please tell me instead of using overridePendingTransition() which method can be used in a class in which we are extending fragments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `overridePendingTransition()` use `getActivity.overridePendingTransition()` in providing animation to **move from fragment to activity**.

Hope this helps...!!